# filter and includes giving unexpected result

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am seeing something very strange here that I cannot figure out. I am trying to return a comma-separated string containing the numbers that occur in elements of `strArr`.

You will see in the argument passed to `FindIntersection` which is `["1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9", "2, 3, 4, 8, 10"]` that `2` occurs in both arrays, but it is not being found in the `filter` `includes` test. Can anyone explain this?

```js
const FindIntersection = (strArr) => {

  const strArrOne = strArr[0].split(',')
  const strArrTwo = strArr[1].split(',')
  const intersection = strArrOne.filter(item => {
    console.log('2',strArrTwo)
    console.log('item --> ', item)
    console.log('includes ---> ', strArrTwo.includes(item))
    return strArrTwo.includes(item)
  }).join(',').replace(/\s/g, '');
  console.log(intersection)
  return intersection;
}
   
console.log(FindIntersection(["1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9", "2, 3, 4, 8, 10"]));
```

Comment: `'2'` and `' 2'` (space) are two different values. You probably want to to split by `/\s*,\s*/`.

Comment: Remove space after comma

Answer (score 2):

There is a leading whitespace for each of the elements in array 1 so you need to trim() the elements before comparing them.

```js
const FindIntersection = (strArr) => {

  const strArrOne = strArr[0].split(',').map(x => x.trim())
  const strArrTwo = strArr[1].split(',').map(x => x.trim())
  const intersection = strArrOne.filter(item => {
    return strArrTwo.includes(item)
  }).join(',').replace(/\s/g, '');
  console.log(intersection)
  return intersection;
}
   
console.log(FindIntersection(["1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9", "2, 3, 4, 8, 10"]));
```

Comment: @peterflanagan glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra whitespace before `2` in first array element, you need to remove that as includes used `===` for checking existence

```js
const FindIntersection = (strArr) => {

  const strArrOne = strArr[0].split(',').map(s=> s.replace(/\s/g,''))
  const strArrTwo = strArr[1].split(',').map(s=> s.replace(/\s/g,''))
  const intersection = strArrOne.filter(item => {
    console.log('2',strArrTwo)
    console.log('item --> ', item)
    console.log('includes ---> ', strArrTwo.includes(item))
    return strArrTwo.includes(item)
  }).join(',').replace(/\s/g, '');
  console.log(intersection)
  return intersection;
}
   
console.log(FindIntersection(["1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9", "2, 3, 4, 8, 10"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the spaces is the simplest fix

```js
const FindIntersection = (strArr) => {

  const strArrOne = strArr[0].split(',')
  const strArrTwo = strArr[1].split(',')
  const intersection = strArrOne.filter(item => {
    console.log('2',strArrTwo)
    console.log('item --> ', item)
    console.log('includes ---> ', strArrTwo.includes(item))
    return strArrTwo.includes(item)
  }).join(',').replace(/\s/g, '');
  console.log(intersection)
  return intersection;
}
   
console.log(FindIntersection(["1,2,4,5,6,9", "2,3,4,8,10"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because expect the first item in arrays, the other items have space before the number. to fix the problem, you can map all item to convert items to a number such as below:

```js
const FindIntersection = strArr => {
    const strArrOne = strArr[0].split(",").map(item => Number(item));
 const strArrTwo = strArr[1].split(",").map(item => Number(item));
    const intersection = strArrOne
        .filter(item => {
            console.log("2", strArrTwo);
            console.log("item --> ", item);
            console.log("includes ---> ", strArrTwo.includes(item));
            return strArrTwo.includes(item);
        })
        .join(",")
        .replace(/\s/g, "");
    console.log(intersection);
    return intersection;
};

console.log(FindIntersection(["1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9", "2, 3, 4, 8, 10"]));
```